# Suppose $f$ is a continuous function and $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ does not exist. How do I prove that $\int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx$ diverges?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, limits

Also, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ is not $\pm\infty$ .

My approach:

Let $F(x)$ be the anti-derivative of $f(x)$. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F'(x)$ = $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} f(x)$ = DNE.

Is it possible to conclude that by L'Hospital, $\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac{F(x)}{x} = \lim\limits_{x\to\infty} F'(x)$ and so $\int_a^\infty f(x) \,dx$ diverges.

I think my approach is wrong but I don't know how else to proceed.

Comment: You cannot apply l'Hospital to something that is not of the form $\infty / \infty$ or $0/0$.

Comment: Consider a function with infinitely many triangular bumps, centered on natural numbers, but the bumps get thinner and thinner, leading to a convergent geometric series as the answer to the integral.

Comment: Isn't that false? The integral $\int_{0}^{\infty }\sin(x^{2})dx$ converges, but $\sin(x^{2})$ doesn't have a limit as $x\rightarrow \infty$.